# Whatever happend to Sciwriter?

Tags: editors, tex-history, wysiwyg

Years ago, when I wrote my thesis, I looked into a project called Sciwriter from a company called soft4science. It was well integrated with LaTeX and it seemed very powerful and structured. It wasn't the intention, I think, but for a big part it looked like it could become finally a decent WYSIWYG LaTeX editor. It even looked better than LyX or TeXmacs at the time.

Do you know what happened with that project, did it change name or was it integrated into another project?

Here it is a screenshot I could find online.

[image: sciwriter]

---

From @touhami comment I could also find what looks like a very similar project, called ScientificAuthor available at CTAN. I created this screenshot:

[image: scientificauthor]

Comment: I think you're looking for http://osl.ugr.es/CTAN/support/scientificauthor/

Comment: Oh goodness, so many toolbars!

Comment: @touhami, it doesn't seem to be the same project but probably a inspired from it. Anyway, thanks for the archaeological work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could track the last archive to the webpage on Oct 2012, the program was sold at $79.00. There is no information there on the author or team that made this program. As far as I can remember it used MikTeX as a backend.

https://web.archive.org/web/20080621005947/http://www.soft4science.com:80/products/SciWriter/s4s_Order_SciWriter.html

Answer (score 0):

maybe [here](https://sciwriter.en.softonic.com/?ex=DSK-173.3)
junk to get large enough

Comment: seems like it does not install on win 8.1 :(

Comment: Not the best prose but at least it has the link to the download, anyway I was mostly curious about the history of the project, rather than installing it. Thanks.

Comment: i only added the junk because it would not accept a short answer. the program seems to have disappeared. most of the links either do not work on do not install for me. so i am trying to learn latex